# What is best strategy for backup on streaming replication(hot standby) environment

Tags: postgresql, backup

I have questions.
What is best strategy for backup on streaming replication(hot standby) environment.
I’d like to do backup on slave server and restore(PITR).

First, I set up streaming replication(hot standby).

1. I tried backup using barman tool on slave.
   But barman tool couldn’t execute on slave because pg_start_backup() can’t be executed on slave sever(read only).
2. I tried backup using pg_basebackup on slave.
   But pg_basebackup is not included wal and wal archive.
   Because I need a PITR(point-in-time-recovery), I tried to copy wal and wal archive from master to slave.
   It was successful but was complicate and also inefficient.

Anyone have good strategy for backup on streaming replication(hot standby) environment?

Also, If  backup is executed on master(about 100GB DB size), How much it has effect on master?

Thanks,

Comment: What PostgreSQL version are you using? `pg_basebackup` supports `-X stream` to copy WAL. (Perhaps you should file a request for pgbarman to support backing up from a standby using `pg_basebackup`, or write a patch?)

Comment: barman claims to be able to take a backup on the slave: http://docs.pgbarman.org/#concurrent_backup_and_backup_from_a_standby

Answer (score 4):

As of `>= 1.3.1` Barman supports backup from a standby replica (`concurrent_backup`). Barman config, e.g. `/etc/barman.d/standby.conf` looks like this:

```
[standby]
description = "Replica of main PostgreSQL DB"
ssh_command = ssh postgres@db02
conninfo = host=db02 user=postgres
backup_options = concurrent_backup
streaming_conninfo = host=db02 user=postgres
streaming_archiver = on
```

If your master is running on PostgreSQL <= 9.5 you'd have to install [pgespresso](https://github.com/2ndquadrant-it/pgespresso) extension (there are binary packages e.g. for Debian from [PGDG APT repos](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt)). PostgreSQL 9.6 introduced native streaming API, there's no need for special extension.

On standby server make sure to configure `archive_command`:

```
wal_level = hot_standby
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'rsync -a %p barman@backup:/var/lib/barman/standby/incoming/%f'
```

the incoming directory should match

```
barman:~$ barman diagnose | grep incoming_wals_directory
```

Also on standby server update `pg_hba.conf` (where `10.0.0.3` is ipaddress of barman server):

```
host   all             postgres            10.0.0.3/32        trust
```

And enable WAL files streaming:

```
barman~$ barman receive-wal standby
```

You can check your configuration using:

```
barman:~$ barman check standby

Server standby:
        PostgreSQL: OK
        wal_level: OK
        directories: OK
        retention policy settings: OK
        backup maximum age: OK (no last_backup_maximum_age provided)
        compression settings: OK
        failed backups: OK (there are 0 failed backups)
        minimum redundancy requirements: OK (have 1 backups, expected at least 0)
        ssh: OK (PostgreSQL server)
        pgespresso extension: OK
        archive_mode: OK
        archive_command: OK
        continuous archiving: OK
        archiver errors: OK
```

Then you should be ready to run full backup:

```
   barman:~$ barman backup standby
```

Answer (score -1):

Please go through below links

http://blog.thecodepath.com/2012/02/13/adventures-in-scaling-part-3-postgresql-streaming-replication/

http://bartek.im/blog/2012/12/04/postgresql-92-streaming-primer.html

and if it is helpful please give feedback.and raise this solution.